# Row equivalent versus equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I understand that if two systems of linear equations are row equivalent (meaning that their augmented matrices can be transformed into each other using elementary row operations) then they have the same solution set.
But why is the reverse statement true? Why is it true that two equivalent systems of linear equations (equivalent meaning that they have the same solution set) of the same size with the same non-empty solution set have row equivalent augmented matrices?

Comment: Note that every matrix has exactly one reduced row-echelon form matrix (one proof [is given here](https://www.cs.uleth.ca/~holzmann/notes/reduceduniq.pdf)). It suffices to show that two distinct RREF matrices will necessarily yield distinct solution sets

Comment: Provided that one of the two distinct RREFs yields a non-empty solution set!

Comment: It suffices to show that two distinct RREF matrices OF THE SAME SIZE will necessarily yield distinct solution sets IF AT LEAST ONE OF THEM YIELDS A NON-EMPTY SOLUTION SET.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your correction

Comment: Of course, two matrices corresponding to an inconsistent system need not be equivalent, but technically have the same solution set